# Select all existing json fields from a postgres table

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In my table `mytable` I have a json field called `data` and I inserted json with a lot of keys & values.

I know that it's possible to select individual fields like so:

```
SELECT data->'mykey' as mykey from mytable
```

But how can I get an overview of all of the json keys on a certain depth? I would have expected something like

```
SELECT data->* from mytable
```

but that doesn't work. Is there something similar?

Comment: What is your PG version? There are major json differences between 9.3 and 9.4

Comment: Not determined yet, but I'll be able to use 9.4 / the latest stable one

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`json_object_keys()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to get all the top-level keys of a `json` value:

```
SELECT keys.* 
FROM mytable, json_object_keys(mytable.data) AS keys (mykey);
```

If you want to search at a deeper level, then first extract that deeper level from the `json` value using the `#>` operator:

```
SELECT keys.* 
FROM mytable, json_object_keys(mytable.data #> '{level1, level2}') AS keys (mykey);
```

Note that the function returns a `set of text`, so you should invoke the function as a row source.

If you are using the `jsonb` data type, then use the `jsonb_object_keys()` function.

Comment: However, that gives me the keys, one per row (which is good, no doubt). But isn't it also possible to get the contents of all keys, i.e. the keys as columns and their values as rows?

Comment: No, that is not possible out-of-the-box. You could write a function to do that but even that would be difficult to use unless the list of keys is known beforehand.If not known, the result from such a function would require the caller to explicitly specify the structure of the returned rows. All in all a very difficult undertaking.